# How to show that $|x^{\beta}| \leq (1+|x|)^{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

Let $x= (x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb R^2.$ Then $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2 +x_2^2}.$
Let $\beta =(\beta_1, \beta_2) \in \mathbb N^2.$ We define $x^{\beta} =x_1^{\beta_1}x_{2}^{\beta_2}.$

> My Questions: (1) Can we say $|x^{\beta}| \leq (1+|x|)^{N}$ for all $\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}\leq N\in \mathbb N.$?
>
> (2) Can we find $\delta>0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{2}|x_{j}|^{N} \geq \delta |x|^{N}$ ?
>
> (3) $1+\delta^{-1} \sum_{j=1}^{2} |x_{j}^N| \leq \delta ^{-1} \sum_{\beta_{1}+\beta_{2}\leq N}|x^{\beta}|$?

If yes, how to justify these questions.

Answer (score 0):

For (1), the answer is yes, since $|x^\beta|\leq|x|^{|\beta|}\leq(1+|x|)^N$.

For (2), if $N$ is fixed, then the answer is yes, since the both sides define two norms in $\mathbb{R}^2$, after taking $N$-th root, and the norms are equivalent for finite dimensional space. But there is no $\delta$ such that the inequality is uniformly valid for all $N$. A counter example is, let $x_1=x_2=x_0>0$, then lhs$=2x_0^N$, rhs$=\delta2^{\frac{N}{2}}x_0^N$, then $\delta\rightarrow 0$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

(3) is false, just let $x_1=x_2=0$.

Comment: Thanks: Why $|x_{1}^{\beta_1}x_{2}^{\beta_{2}}|=\sqrt{(x_{1}^{\beta_{1}}x_{2}^{\beta_{2}})^2} \leq (x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^2)^{(\beta_{1}+\beta_{2})/2}$?

Comment: @abcd Not this inequality, but the inequality $|x_i|\leq |x|$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all your three questions should be *yes*. ((3) is true if one use the convention that $0$ is an element in $\mathbb{N}$ and $0^0:=1$.)

I would like to point out a background information for your question, the generalization of which in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is used in a proof of a useful characterization of the Schwartz space in Folland's *Real Analysis*:

> [image]

The first sentence in the proof can be done by the same idea in Cuteboy's answer. Note that Folland also gives a nice proof for your second question, where he exploits certain symmetry of the express ("... both sides are homogeneous of degree $N$") to reduce the inequality to the case when $|x|=1$. Your third question appears in the very last inequality above.